# Android - Looper.prepare() in a Thread vs Activity.runOnUIThread()

Tags: android, multithreading, android-looper, android-runonuithread

My question is quite simple but I'm not able to find a satisfying answer. The question is: Does my thread run on UI Thread if I call `Looper.prepare()` at the start of my `Runnable`?

I know `Looper` is for `MessageQueue` and exchanging data between threads but does it make the code run on UI Thread?

Below code will explain:

```
@Override
public void onReceive(final Context context, Intent intent) {
if(intent.getAction().equals(ConnectivityManager.CONNECTIVITY_ACTION)) {

        Runnable runnable = new Runnable() {
            @Override
            public void run() {
                Looper.prepare();
                // ... some code ... //
                Looper.loop();
            }
        };

        Thread thread = new Thread(runnable);
        thread.start();
    }
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No, it will not make your thread run on UI thread. For more info see: [Communicating with the UI Thread](https://developer.android.com/training/multiple-threads/communicate-ui.html)

Comment: Thanks, that all I needed to know. GOD bless you